# How do I show the font-family 'Gill Sans' in svg of an ionic/angular build?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, svg, ionic6

I'am using a logo in a WebApp I'm developing for my company. It is a .svg-File that uses the font "Gill Sans". Everything was working fine while development, but when i provided the build, the font falls back to a default one. In the svg-File itself you can find the style property with "GillSans" as font-family. What am I missing/doing wrong? Do I have to import that font family? If yes, how?

Thank you in advance for your help!

How it looks with ionic build:

[image: wrong font]

How it looks with ionic s:

[image: Gill Sans]

Source code of svg-File:

```
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
        <g transform="matrix(1.28782,0,0,1.28782,-25.1285,-31.1994)">
            <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-138.262,-23.116)">
                <circle cx="551.555" cy="418.307" r="312.421" style="fill:white;"/>
            </g>
            <g transform="matrix(1.20107,0,0,1.21628,-10.9294,89.9381)">
                <clipPath id="_clip1">
                    <rect x="32.794" y="272.932" width="649.427" height="326.98"/>
                </clipPath>
                <g clip-path="url(#_clip1)">
                    <circle cx="357.507" cy="275.198" r="324.713" style="fill:rgb(252,191,42);"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g transform="matrix(1.01638,0,0,1.01638,-216.129,36.5656)">
                <path d="M623.119,-12.14C839.07,-12.14 1014.39,163.185 1014.39,379.136C1014.39,595.088 839.07,770.413 623.119,770.413C407.168,770.413 231.843,595.088 231.843,379.136C231.843,163.185 407.168,-12.14 623.119,-12.14ZM623.119,85.679C785.082,85.679 916.576,217.173 916.576,379.136C916.576,541.1 785.082,672.594 623.119,672.594C461.155,672.594 329.662,541.1 329.662,379.136C329.662,217.173 461.155,85.679 623.119,85.679Z" style="fill:rgb(78,76,80);"/>
            </g>
            <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-94.8002,-90.0861)">
                <g transform="matrix(144.372,0,0,144.51,-22834,-22477.1)">
                    <text x="159.734px" y="159.799px" style="font-family:'GillSans', 'Gill Sans', sans-serif;font-size:2.095px;fill:rgb(78,76,80);">SAM</text>
                </g>
                <g transform="matrix(-5.58319,-2.15552e-15,9.79022e-16,-4.13153,4511.24,2729.5)">
                    <path d="M685.093,530.291L689.57,538.113L680.615,538.113L685.093,530.291Z" style="fill:rgb(78,76,80);"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I imagine you would have to import it, yes. And if you're converting it to a png you might need to make it a data url too.

Comment: You definitely need to include your font as a data url to make it self contained. See also: [Why is my SVG file not using my font file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060147/why-is-my-svg-file-not-using-my-font-file/71065128#71065128). Honestly, I 'd rather rebuild the logo in a graphic app (e.g) and convert all texts to paths. This way you get a perfectly self contained svg that works everywhere: in editors, image viewers and web apps.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answers. @herrstrietzel What do you mean by 'convert all texts to paths'? Texts like 'SAM' or the <text>-Tag ? Sorry, I don't really get it.

Comment: You can convert the `<text>`  (containing SAM)  element  to a `<path>`  geometry element. This way you don't need the used font installed or embedded. You can also convert your svg to other vector formats like `pdf` or `eps` easily. This is actually the most common practice for print logos. [Tutorial](https://designbundles.net/design-school/text-to-path-in-inkscape)