# Retaining the font when exporting vectorized images from python `plotly`

Tags: python, svg, fonts, plotly

I am trying to export a vectorized image from `plotly`, but am wondering why the `.svg` export does not retain the text font. The idea is to export in `.svg`, organize some images in Inkscape and then export the complex image as `.png`, but I'd need the images with the same font as my Overleaf LaTeX document.
Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [5, 6, 8, 2, 4, 3]
data = np.column_stack([a, b])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])
fig = px.scatter(df)
fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(family="Computer Modern", size=25),
)
fig.write_image('png.png')
fig.write_image('svg.svg')
```

[image: inkscape snippet of the svg file]
[image: png file retaining the font]

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough in this matter to explain it to you, but the following fonts can help. `fig.update_layout(font=dict(family="Serif", size=25),)`

Comment: Didn't all solutions below solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, the solutions solved the problem. I'm not the OP so I can't mark it answered, but I added the bounty, and that can't be awarded until 24h passes.

Comment: @DavidParks , but why did you add the bounty if one of the solutions solved your problem?

Comment: There were no solutions to the question when the bounty was added @Hamzah

Answer (score 2):

### Crucial for conversion: Is the font available for all applications?

LaTeX's "Computer Modern" is probably **not globally available** on your OS.
See also: ["Where can I find computer modern fonts for use in other programs, e.g. Adobe Illustrator?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill)

### SVG exports won't embed any fonts

That's why you see a "Times New Roman" as a **fallback**.
For usage in web browsers, you can actually [embed fonts as base 64 encoded data-URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060147/why-is-my-svg-file-not-using-my-font-file/71065128#71065128).

Unfortunately, most desktop applications – like Inkscape – can't read or use these embedded font data-chunks.

### Workaround: Install the font locally on your system

1. Open Inkscape an add a text element.
2. Check if "Computer Modern" is listed in the font selection drop down.
3. If not: either find a copy in your LaTex directory or download a copy of the font-family (e.g on [fontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern))
4. Install the font-family locally/globally.
5. Open Inkscape again you should close all other Inkscape instances  to refresh all font caches.
6. Search for the previously installed font in the dropdown again
7. Depending on the source it might have another font-family name like "CMU Sans Serif" (fontSqirrel version)
8. Update the font-family on export to the globally available font family name e.g.

```py
fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(family="CMU Sans Serif", size=25),
)
```

All text elements should be rendered correctly – albeit we're actually replacing the font-family by a visually identical local copy.

### Font (family) names:

Depending on your OS and your font file, you might need to **test different font names** (especially older font files usually contain multiple font name records for compatibility reasons).

You could try to parse your font in [fontdrop](https://fontdrop.info/)
Check the **"Data" Tab.**

Answer (score -1):

Solution (with due credit to commentators):

```
fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(family="arial", size=18)
)
```

I had a similar problem and came here for an answer. The comments were helpful. To expand on the problem, the vectorized version of the plot (SVG/PDF) were coming through to Illustrator as a clipping group instead of staying as a font.

I found the following recommended solution in `matplotlib` as well:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
plt.rcParams.update({'font.family':'Arial'})
```

Two details that were important that I initially overlooked:

- `arial` needed to be lowercase in my system, `Arial` did not work. The solution in comments worked, but I didn't initially noticed because of capitalization.
- In Illustrator, you need to ungroup and move some invisible objects that are on top of the font before you can edit the font, that detail is a bit confusing at first.

Comment: The "Computer Modern" font that is asked for and shown in the second image is a serif font.  Why are you suggesting to replace it with arial which is just the opposite?  And why are you talking about Illustrator when the question was about Inkscape?

Comment: Fair point, I came here with nearly the same question in Illustrator (Inkscape being the open source version if Illustrator), so I'm answering a nearly identical variant here and commenting on details that tripped me up along the way. The other answer should be the accepted answer, but this answer provides further detail related to the question that's likely to be useful to others in the future. The core of the question is about how to configure plotly to work with vector graphics applications correctly, the font and choice of application are variables to the core question.