# Nabla font doesn’t have the correct fill color on iPhones

Tags: css, webfonts

[Should be orange color font here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Nhe.jpg)

[This is how the font should be displayed on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bDZI.jpg)

In my code I only adjust the font size when making the site mobile friendly. On Android phones it appears 'normal' with the text as the color orange. I've had this occur on safari and chrome on all iphones.

Below is my entire CSS file as well as my HTML where I link the google font, any ideas?

HTML (where I link to the google font)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Match Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat&family=Libre+Baskerville&family=Nabla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

CSS (where I declare the Google Font and make adjustments for smaller screen sizes)

```
h1, p, #playAgain, button{
    font-family: 'Nabla', sans-serif !important;
}



@media (min-width: 319px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    h1{
        font-size: 3.5rem; 
    }


    #normal, #hard{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .front{
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }

    .back, img{
        border-radius: 0rem;
    }

    #buttonContainer{
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 991px){
    h1{
        font-size: 5rem;
    }

    .front{
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }

    .back, img{
        border-radius: 0rem;
    }

    #buttonContainer{
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

    #normal, #hard{
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    h1{
        margin: 0;
    }
```

I was expecting the Google Font to appear orange like it does on desktop and Android devices.

Comment: Nabla indeed uses [quite new features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448101/is-it-possible-to-extract-an-svg-from-a-rendered-truetype-font/). However, it should work on current iOS versions (Can't reproduce this issue. See codepen [example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/JjxpMRX) )

Comment: @herrstrietzel your codepen does not work on my iPhone which is running iOS 17.1.1. The glyph shapes are correct but the fill is solid black.

Comment: @Brett Donald: sorry you're right - I haven't updated my iOs for quite some time (it actually works before 17). IOS has quite recently removed support for COLR-V1/2 Opentype svg feature. Maybe it caused rendering problems that haven't been solved yet. (Not a big surprise, as it's certainly a challenge for the text rendering engine to include gradients also supporting css transitions).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a snippet for testing on iOS.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nabla&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: Nabla;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
It was the best of times, it was the worst of times
```

It renders as follows for me on iOS 17.1.1:

[image: text in Nabla font rendered on iOS; outlines are correct but fill is solid black]

Nabla’s [product page](https://nabla.typearture.com) claims that:

> Nabla is currently only supported in Chrome.

With the exception of Chrome on iOS, because there Chrome uses the WebKit rendering engine as mandated by Apple. So Chrome on iOS renders identically to Safari. (As soon as WebKit adds support, all iOS browsers will get the feature.)

Nabla’s [product page](https://nabla.typearture.com) refers visitors to [this entry on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/colr-v1) for tracking browser support for the underlying technology.