# Why text inside an svg logo with google fonts not rendered properly on a webpage?

Tags: html, svg, text, google-fonts

I am trying to design a simple logo for my webpage using text in an SVG file and for the text I am using google fonts.

Here is my SVG file:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="56" viewBox="0 0 240 56">
  <style>
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titan+One");
  </style>

  <text fill="#fac31e" font-size="3em" font-family="Titan One" x="1" y="45">
        MyLogo
    </text>
</svg>
```

When I save the file and click on it on my Mac computer, the image opens, and I see the word `MyLogo` is rendered correctly with font `Titan One`.

However, when I add it to my website using:

```
<img class="logo" style="font-family: Titan One" src="/img/my-logo.svg" alt="My Logo" width="140" height="120">
```

It shows the text `MyLogo`, but it is rendered with a different font. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are using it as an embedded image, which is a wholy separate document being rendered inside an image tag, which means whatever CSS you apply will not translate into it (just like with iframes). I'm also not sure resources embedded like that can request more resources (like loading a font from google).

Comment: it's because you are using external fonts.

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere and enxaneta for the comments. So what is the solution?

Comment: @TJ1 you should use <object>

Comment: Maybe the `object` tag, I see the answer but honestly haven't really used it myself. I would add the text to the SVG and then outline it with your image editor so all fonts are ommitted and text is rendered as curves, which will guarantee the look you want and means one less resource need to be loaded.

Comment: @somethinghere that could work too. Can you please let me know what image editor can do that? Is there any free one or online one I can use?

Comment: I guess InkScape if you are looking for a free open-source version of something like illustrator? I use Affinity Designer, which is cheaper than illustrator (one time payment, no subscription) but not free. Pretty sure InkScape can do the job, I just never use it myself. Any vector editor can outline fonts I think.

Comment: See also ["Why is my SVG file not using my font file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060147/why-is-my-svg-file-not-using-my-font-file/71065128#71065128). In short I highly recommend to convert your Logo text to paths - this way your logo can be previewed and opened in any application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <object> instead of <img>. Here's the code:

```html
<object data="/img/my-logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" alt="My Logo" width="140" height="120">
```

Comment: Great, yes it is working if I use object and instead of src use data, great answer, thanks a lot.